# How do I pass HTML tags through getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pass a json_encode-d array from PHP to JavaScript using JQuery's getJSON, and then display it in the HTML.  It works fine in all cases except when I want to pass basic HTML tags, e.g. 3<sup>4</sup> shows up as:

```
3<sup>4</sup>
```

It works fine when I have:

```
var myVar = <?php echo json_encode(jsonArray); ?>;
```

But I need to use getJSON as well.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Maybe a regex I failed to figure out?

Comment: Pass data *from where* to JavaScript?  What exactly are you sending and what are you receiving?  This is really not clear at all.

Comment: `getJSON` and `json_encode` do not do the same thing. `getJSON` is an AJAX call that returns a JSON object; however, what you're returning via AJAX needs to be a properly formatted JSON string. `json_encode` in your example is just turning an array into a properly formatted JSON string.

Comment: @Drew - of course - so the PHP json_encode makes the PHP array into a properly formatted JSON string, and getJSON passes it to a JavaScript object.  How do I unescape the HTML tags in one of those fields so that when they are added to the document with innerHTML or createTextNode they will be treated as HTML tags and not strings?

Comment: You could just do a string replace on it `.replace("\", "")` when you're adding it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('#YourTarget').html( $('<div/>').html(yourStringFromJSON).text());`

For example:

`$('h1').html( $('<div/>').html('Hola&lt;sup&gt;Hey&lt;/sup&gt;').text());`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex to unescape the forward slash:

```
var cleanString = dirtyString.replace(/\\\//g,"/");
```